# How exactly does code completion work in Eclipse?

Tags: ide, eclipse

It seems that code completion (e.g. intellisense) is a hit or miss thing within Eclipse/ForceIDE plugin.

Is there a page or something that spells out how and when it actually works?

Comment: How and when it works? Poorly :) I've basically given up on it, it's very intermittent and often just goes into hiding. If you're on OSX, you may want to give MavensMate a shot, I've heard great things but am not an OSX guy myself. (https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText)

Comment: @jkraybill I am on Windows and they do have a windows installations directions as well.  Some things worked and some didn't. The whole Sublime Text is such a huge improvement over Eclipse that I was sold in 5 minutes.

Comment: Whoa awesome! I didn't realise you can run it on Windows now -- will have to give it a go.

Comment: @jkraybill Don't get your hopes up though - the code completion is a mixed bag.  Apex code indexing doesn't really work.

Answer (score -1):

Try right clicking on the line you're working on or a blank line. You'll then get "content assist". Is that what you're referring to? Just like when working from within SF UI, it's very limited. You basically need to know the code and what you plan to write.

Once you start typing something, it sometimes will present a pop-up, particularly when you type a `.` and present you with context options that you can select. More often than not, I personally find the feature to be a nuisance. I've never searched the SF Help (there's a specific one for the IDE in the drop down) to see how it's supposed to work.